# No container uid/gid created?

Tags: docker

I thought that docker *doesn't* namespace uids and gids, i.e. two users, one on the host and one in the container, with different names but the same uid are actually the same user as there's only a single kernel. so they must have identical permissions.

But when I run a container which has a line like:

```
RUN groupadd -g 1001 appuser && \
    useradd -r -u 1001 -g appuser appuser
```

...in the Dockerfile, how come I can't see the uid or gid values of 1001 in the output of `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` resp. on the *host*?

Comment: A user in a docker container does not have to exist on the host system. In fact, It does not have to exist in the container either. Choose a random uid/guid you know does not exist on your host nor container and try `docker run -it -u <uid>:<gid> <your_image>` and see the result. Anyhow adding a user inside an image will add that user... in the image, not on your system (and that's quite fortunate!).

Comment: Yeah I think I figured out what was confusing me. The uid/gid are NOT namespaced, but the *user names* and *group names* are namespaced. And `/etc/passwd` on the host will just show the host's mapping of user names to uids, ignoring any mappings from user names to uids which the container may have.